# Related Posts by taxonomy using Advance Custom Fields Plugin

Tags: taxonomy, terms, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to list related posts using taxonomy with the Advance Custom Fields plugin.

I’m using the following code below from the docs that links to all the posts in the taxonomy, but is it possible to query a list of related posts on the single.php rather than just linking to the term archive? I've been trying to do this for hours and can't work out if it's possible to do that.

Thanks

```
<?php

    $terms = get_field('more_scenemaker');

    if( $terms ): ?>

    <ul>

<?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">View all '<?php echo $term->name; ?>' posts</a>


<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [relations field from ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/). Then you could select your own related posts for each blog item.

Comment: Thanks, that's my plan B if I can't get it to happen automagically.